# Responzive background image?

Tags: css

как написать такой фон для сайта (адаптив)

https://www.webfx.com/blog/images/assets/cdn.sixrevisions.com/0431-01_responsive_background_image_demo/responsive-full-background-image-demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно из примера - вот так:

**css**

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://www.webfx.com/blog/images/assets/cdn.sixrevisions.com/images/background-photo.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

А в мобильной версии просто подгружается изображение размером поменьше:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  body {
      background-image: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);
  }
}
```

А вот подробное руководство, которое можно почитать нажав в примере кнопку "tutorial".

https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/responsive-background-image/